# Flask + Next.js application: Missing Cookie

Tags: javascript, python, flask, cookies, cors

I am currently trying to figure out how to get my cookies to send back and forth between my flask backend and next.js frontend. I have spent a couple of days trying different things but I keep getting the error "msg": "Missing cookie "access_token_cookie"". When I console log the document.cookie I am getting all the expected tokens.

First, I log in on my front end by getting my backend server and setting the cookies:

```js
try {
      const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password,
        }),
      });

      console.log(response);

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.access_token);

        const access_token = data.access_token;
        const refresh_token = data.refresh_token;
        const access_csrf_token = data.access_csrf_token;
        Cookies.set("access_token_cookie", access_token);
        Cookies.set("refresh_token_cookie", refresh_token);
        Cookies.set("access_csrf_token_cookie", access_csrf_token);
        console.log(document.cookie);

        if (data.User.is_admin) {
          router.push("/admin/dashboard");
        } else {
          router.push("/user/profile");
        }
```

This is the page that I want to render when I use router.push() and the user is an admin, and this is also where the error is when it tries to do the fetch it says that the access_token_cookie is not set.

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const access_token = Cookies.get("access_token_cookie");
const csrf = Cookies.get("access_csrf_token_cookie");

const AdminDashboard = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const dataFetch = async () => {
      const data = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/dashboard", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf,

          //   "Authorization": `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        },
        credentials: "same-origin",
      });

      setData(data);
      console.log(data);
      console.log(document.cookie);
    };
    dataFetch();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Ud</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <div>hello guys</div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default AdminDashboard;
```

And then here is the /admin/dashboard end point in flask:

```py
@admin_bp.route('/admin/dashboard', methods=["GET"])
@admin_required()
def dashboard():
    claim = get_jwt()
    current_user_id = get_jwt_identity()
    user = User.query.get(current_user_id)
    resp = jsonify(
        {
            "Message": f"Got protected information for ADMIN USER {user.username}",
            "User": user.serialize(),
            "claim": claim
        }
    )
    resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return resp, 200
```

as well as the login end point:

```py
@auth_bp.route("/auth/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    data = check_json_and_validate_schema(request, login_user_schema)
    email, password = (data["email"], data["password"])
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    if user is None:
        return jsonify({"error": "User not found"}), 401
    if not bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        return jsonify({"error": "Incorrect Password"}), 401

    if user.is_admin:
        access_token = create_access_token(
            identity=user.id, additional_claims={"is_admin": True}, expires_delta=timedelta(days=100))
        refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=user.id)
        resp = jsonify(
            {
                "Message": f"Successfully logged in ADMINISTRATIVE user {user.username}",
                "User": user.serialize(),
                "access_token": access_token,
                "access_csrf_token": get_csrf_token(access_token),
                "refresh_token": refresh_token,
                "refresh_csrf_token": get_csrf_token(refresh_token)
            }
        )

        set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
        set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)
        return resp, 200
    else:
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.id)
        refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=user.id)

        resp = jsonify(
            {
                "Message": f"Successfully logged in basic user {user.username}",
                "User": user.serialize(),
                "access_token": access_token,
                "access_csrf_token": get_csrf_token(access_token),
                "refresh_token": refresh_token,
                "refresh_csrf_token": get_csrf_token(refresh_token)
            }
        )

        set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
        set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)
        return resp, 200
```

Flask is running on port 5000 and nextjs is on port 3000. Does anybody have any idea how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you set your cookie domain? i think in your `set_access_cookies()` method you haven't set your domain path just like referenced by this [documentation](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/?highlight=set_access_cookie#flask_jwt_extended.set_access_cookies)

Comment: _Flask is running on port 5000 and nextjs is on port 3000._ Different ports imply different Web origins. Yet you configure your request with `credentials: "same-origin"`. That cannot work.

Comment: @ryaneatdinosaurs Why would setting the cookie's domain help? I don't think the `Domain` attribute does what you think it does.

Comment: @jub0bs 
I have figured it out! I had to get rid of the cors initialiser in my flask app, removed the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header and created a proxy in next.config.js that had a rewrite in it

source: "/:slug*"
destination: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/:slug*"

The error had to do with the ports being different, meaning that the front end would not send any cookies back to the backend once they had been set on login. I'm still not sure why CORS in my flask app didn't fix this though...Any thoughts?

Sorry I've not been coding very long so i'm very new to all these things

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that's trying to figure this out - what fixed it for me was **updating the development domain to '.lvh.me'**.  Chrome has security nuances when it comes to cookie storage on localhost.  I also should note that my NextJS app utilizes the subdomain of auth.lvh.me for the authorization functionality, and upon successful login it redirects the user over to app.lvh.me.

**Flask Setup**

Here's my flask_jwt_extended config:

```
# Configure application to store JWTs in cookies
JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION = ['cookies']

# Only allow JWT cookies to be send over https.  In production, this should be True
    JWT_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT = True
    JWT_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".lvh.me"
    JWT_SAME_SITE = "Lax"
    JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES = timedelta(hours=1)
```

Also here's my CORS setup.  In particular take note of the supports_credentials argument being set to True, that's very important.

```
CORS(app, origin=['http://auth.localhost:3000', 'http://app.localhost:3000', 'http://auth.lvh.me:3000', 'http://app.lvh.me:3000'], supports_credentials=True)
```

**NextJS Setup**
Not much had to change here except the endpoints being called:

```
  const response = await fetch('http://lvh.me:5000/login', { ...
```

What's most important is that for any subsequent API calls that are leveraged after you login, is you must include `credentials: include` as part of your requests, like this:

```
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://lvh.me:5000/use_case/1', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            credentials: 'include'
        })
```

Hope this helps someone out!